# Convert strings (list of strings) into regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of srings:

```
lista = ['Word', 'Apple', 'Banana']
```

How can I convert this into regex:

```
reg = "\b(word1|word2|word3)\b"
```

My target is to speed-up my function (for a dataframe):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace(reg, r'\XXX', regex=True)
```

Comment: `regex = r'\b(' + "|".join(list) + r')\b'`. but its not a good idea to call your list as `list` as you will overwrite the python built in of list

Comment: thx, with the error: multiple repeat at postion , I have to do `regex = re.escape(..) `or?

Comment: Sorry i dont get what you mean. When i test with `print(re.findall(regex, "This is an Apple tree and not a Banana tree"))` i get the output `['Apple', 'Banana']` so the regex works

Comment: yeah, but this is a sample dataset, If I have different data in it...

Comment: I can only work off the sample you provided